# Windows XP Scheduled task running under wrong profile

Tags: windows-xp, windows-task-scheduler

I have a scheduled task on Windows XP SP3 that among other things launches a headless Virtual Box machine.

- The task is configured to use the administrator account
- The VirtualBox config file is located in C:\Documents and Settings\Administartor.VirtualBox

The task occasionally fails to locate the VirtualBox config file. (Maybe once a week)

After some digging around I can see the the when the task fails it is looking for the config file in the C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.VirtualBox folder.

This leads me to believe that the system account is being used and not the administrator account.

The only issue I can think of is that the Administrator may not always be logged in.

Is there a way to force the task scheduler to use the proper profile when running?

Thanks

Comment: How exactly did you configure the task "to use the administrator account"?

Comment: In the properties dialog of the scheduled task I have 'Run as' set to hostname\Administrator, where hostname is the name computer the task is running on.